# ADF - evaluate three conditions in If block

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have three activities (A, B, C) that need to return a string = 'True' in order for the If block to run its True activities, otherwise False activities.

**Scenario 1 (All True):**

A = True

B = True -> if A & B & C = True then True

C = True

**Scenario 2 (At least one False):**

True

False -> if A & B & C != True then False

True

I have tried to simplify the expression to this;

```
@and(
   equals('True', 
    'True'), # True = True, True
and(
    equals('True', 
    'True'),  # True = True, True
    equals('True', 
    'True')  # True = True, True
    )  # True & True, True

 # True & True, return True
)
```

However, this throws an error:

`The function 'bool' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type`

How can I go about evaluating all three (3) conditions?

I have also tried using another and() such that it becomes this to no avail (same error msg):

```
@and(
and(
   equals('True', 
    'True'),
     true
   ), 
and(
    equals('True', 
    'True'),  
    equals('True', 
    'True')  
    )  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### True Condition

@and(equals(Activity A),'True'),equals(Activity B),'True'))-Set a variable Z =true
@and(equals(Activity Z),'True'),equals(Activity C),'True'))-Set a variable result =true

### False Condition

@or(equals(Activity A),'False'),equals(Activity B),'False'))-Set a variable Z =False
@or(equals(Activity Z),'False'),equals(Activity C),'False'))-Set a variable result =False

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be one way of solving it.

```
@and(
bool(equals('True', 
    'True')),
and(
    equals('True', 
    'True'),
    equals('True', 
    'True')
    )
)
```